# change name of checkbox onclick

Tags: javascript

I need to change the name attribute of a checkbox when its clicked using javascript but Im not sure how to do this. This is what Ive tried:

```
$("#first").click(function() {

$(#first).attr("name", thatName);

alert(#first).attr("name");
});
```

`<input type="checkbox" name="thisName" id="first">`

No good!  Any help is appreciated.

Edit... i think i got it!... Can anyone provide feedback on this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").click(function() {
        $("#first").attr("name", "chump");
        alert($("#first").attr("name"));
    });
});
```

It works, but Id like to hear anyones thoughts on whether it might present problems.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the quotes for the string:

```
$("#first").click(function() {

    $("#first").attr("name", thatName);

});
```

But you don't need to do `$('#first')` in the first place as the `this` object is now set to it:

```
$("#first").click(function() {

    $(this).attr("name", thatName);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `#first` with `this` inside the function.

```
$("#first").click(function() {

    // you need to first assign a value to thatName
    $(this).attr("name", thatName);
    alert($(this).attr("name"));

});
```

Note: You need to wrap the whole `alert` message in parentheses. And don't forget the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes-

```
var thatName = "chkBox";
$("#first").click(function() {
    $("#first").attr("name", thatName);
    alert("#first").attr("name");
});
```